# How do I prevent handheld devices from opening the keyboard when using a canvas signature pad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, knockout.js

I have a little confirmation window in my app where the user has to enter a name and message, then put their signature. My problem is that when a user enters a name, the focus of the application doesn't do a away the moment someone uses the signature pad, causing the virtual keyboard to pup up the moment the user releases their finger from the touch screen. This focus problem only seems to occur on mobile devices and happens on both android and apple devices.

I've tried using JQuery and Javascript and even Knockout solutions like focus.blur and .focus() but nothing seems to work. It's like clicking on the HTML5 canvas on mobile devices doesn't take away focus.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form-group params="value: NameSignatory, attr: {'data-test-id':'name'}"></form-group>
        <form-group params="value: EmailSignatory, attr: {'data-test-id':'email'}"></form-group>
        <form-group params="value: SignatoryComment, attr: {'data-test-id':'comment'}"></form-group>

        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback" data-bind="validationElement: SignatureJson">
            <label class="large">Put your signature here:</label>
            <em class="help-block" data-bind="validationMessage: SignatureJson"></em>
            <signature-pad-v2 params="json: SignatureJson, imageUrl: ImageFileUrl"></signature-pad-v2>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
define([
    "knockout",
    "jquery",
    "szimek-signature-pad",
    "text!./signature-pad-v2.html"
], function (ko, $, SignaturePad, template) {

    return {
        template: template,
        viewModel: {
            createViewModel: function (params, componentInfo) {
                var canvas,
                    signaturePad,
                    clearButton,
                    $element = $(componentInfo.element),
                    imageUrl = params.imageUrl ? params.imageUrl : ko.observable(),
                    json = params.json ? params.json : ko.observable(),
                    variableBorder = params.variableBorder ? params.variableBorder : ko.observable(1)
                    ;

                var callbacks = {
                    regenerateFromJson: function (data) {
                        signaturePad.fromData(data);
                    },
                    regenerateFromDataUrl: function (data) {
                        signaturePad.fromDataURL(data);
                    }
                };

                if (params.context) {
                    params.context(callbacks);
                }

                return {
                    init: function () {
                        console.log('signature-pad-v2 started', $element);
                        canvas = $element.find("canvas").get(0);
                        signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas,
                            {
                                minWidth: 1,
                                maxWidth: 2,
                                penColor: "rgb(51,97,155)",
                                backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                                onEnd: function () {
                                    json(signaturePad.toData());
                                    imageUrl(signaturePad.toDataURL());
                                }
                            });

                        document.getElementById("signature-pad-v2").style.border = ko.unwrap(variableBorder) + "px solid #c0c0c0";
                        
                        clearButton = $element.find(".clearButton a");

                        clearButton.bind("click", function (evt) {
                            evt.preventDefault();
                            signaturePad.clear();                           
                            return true;
                        });

                        if (imageUrl()) {
                            signaturePad.fromDataURL(imageUrl());
                        }
                        else {
                            if (json()) {
                                signaturePad.fromData(json());
                            }
                        }

                        if (params.context) {
                            params.context(callbacks);
                        }

                    }
                };

            }
        }
    };

});
```

When the user puts their signature on a mobile device, focus doesn't get removed from the text fields and the keyboard will pop up once they release their finger. An annoying little inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to remove the focus from an element it is necessary for another element to take focus. Have you tried to make the component 'focusable'?

Try adding the attribute tabindex="0" to your signature-pad-v2, or to sub-element generated by your component.

Comment: I tried adding tabindex="0" to the canvas itself but that didn't seem to do anything. Should I combine tabindex="0"  with another solution?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the tabindex attribute to the main element generated by signaturepad, modifying the library. Alternatively, you could inject the attribute via jQuery.

Comment: I added it in the main element in the framework of my app. It works fine on desktop (did before the index as well) but it doesn't work on mobile devices for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Without a complete example, it is difficult to say what the problem is, but since you are using jQuery try to blur the active element as follows:

```
$('canvas').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

Also, if it doesn't work, try to disable the default action by adding `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Added the script to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<canvas inputMode="none" onTouchStart={() => {
if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.blur) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
}
    }}
     />
```

Just blur active element,that hide keyboard. Vanilla js solution.